# Install issues with TFS 2015 with MS SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, tfs, tfs-2015

I am trying to install TFS 2015 with MS SQL Server 2016 and it went very well few times. Later I removed the MS SQL Server 2016 from my machine and re-installed it and i found following error.

Any clue, what it could have gone wrong in this case. I did refer https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx and found that System Requirements is matching as well.

```
TF401159: The SQL Server instance you specified (localhost

\SqlExpress) is version 13.0.1601.5, which cannot be used in place or 

upgraded. For more information about supported versions of SQL Server, 

visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd578592(v=vs.120).aspx
```

However, the url of MSDN is not uptodate for TFS 2015.

Comment: What's the meaning of removed the SQL Server and re-installed it? Do you mean you have installed SQL Server and TFS, then removed and re-install SQL Server? Why did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that only TFS 2015.3 and TFS 15 supports SQL Server 2016, please check your TFS 2015 edition.

More information of Requirement, check:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements